# Prevent animation on rotation of one specific UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, rotation

I have a full-screen `UIView`. When I rotate the phone the view shrinks a little (and you see the black background) and then expands again to be full-screen. It basically animates as expected.
The other views on the screen also animate accordingly.

Can I prevent this from happening for one specific view?
I would like the full-screen view to just stay full-screen without animation revealing the black background, but maintain that the other views animate their rotation.

Kind of like how Apple does it in the camera app. The "viewfinder" does not animate its rotation, but the buttons do.

I have the following code in my `ViewController`. `liveView` is the the full-screen `UIView` mentioned.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(in: self.liveView, animation: { (context) in

        if let connection = (self.liveView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection {
            connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(ui: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation)
        }

        }, completion: nil)

}
```

`AVCaptureVideoOrentation` is an extension which basically translates `UIInterfaceOrientation` to `AVCaptureVideoOrientation` with a `switch` statement.

Thanks
- Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `self.liveView.layer.removeAllAnimations()`:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(in: self.liveView, animation: { (context) in

        if let connection = (self.liveView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection {
            connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(ui: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation)
        }


        self.liveView.layer.removeAllAnimations()


        }, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. In addition it adds a weird white view that also starts animating.